# With JSP, does the taglib URI mean that my site is reliant on the URI resolving?

Tags: java, jsp, sitemesh

I'm trying to implement a sitemesh decorator in my site. The example on their site has a full URI linking to their site for the taglib part of the decorator file:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator" prefix="decorator" %>
```

Does this mean that my site is reliant on being able to access that site? Because i want to deploy inside an intranet which can't access the outside world.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it does not. The URI declared in `taglib` will be resolved locally as long as it matches the URI declared in tag library descriptor (or in your `web.xml`, depending on what JSP version your container implements).

See [Java EE tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnamu.html) for more details.

Comment: When you say 'resolved locally' do you mean that if i have the TLD file in my LIB folder i'll be fine?

Comment: TLD doesn't belong in `lib`, it should either be in `/WEB-INF` or in `/META-INF` of the jar providing tags. But yes, you'll be fine.

Comment: Awesome, i opened the JAR in 7-zip and it does indeed have those files in the meta-inf folder. You've set my mind at rest. Thanks

Comment: PS: The jar i looked in was 'sitemesh-2.4.2.jar'

Comment: @ChssPly76 I finally just got done resolving a similar issue.. and for the life of me could not find the correct documentation for Java SE 7... can someone point me to a more official source than http://www.di.unipi.it/~ghelli/didattica/bdldoc/A97329_03/web.902/a95882/taglibs.htm? What would be the correct process for finding the correct documentation for this?

Answer (score 4):

No. The URI is a Universal Resource Identifier, it is NOT a locator (URL). This means that the URI is used to uniquely identify each taglib in an internal registry of taglibs, much like a key is used to set/get values from a `HashMap` or `Hashtable` in Java.

According to the web application spec from Sun, resolving the URIs to actual tag libraries that can be loaded/called by the application takes place in the following order:

1. Check the `web.xml` file for matching `taglib` tags that have the given URI in them and then follow the `taglib-location` tag to actually load the TLD.
2. If no match with #1 was found, recursively check the `META-INF` directory of all the JARs in the application for TLDs that contain the URI that was specified.

Comment: But it **is** a URL in this case :-) Depending on how your JSPs are marked up / handled it can even be used like one (for parsing XML form, for example).

Comment: I have the feeling that answering this won't make things clearer :)

Answer (score 0):

`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" >`

where the `uri` attribute value resolves to a location the container understands and the `prefix` attribute informs a container what bits of markup are custom actions.